# How to export product to amazon store from a CSV file using PHP [MWS]?

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I want to upload export products to amazon store from a csv file using MWS in PHP. I've uploaded product using a CSV file in amazon seller central "Add products" section. In that the product was aded successfully. But I want to do this from my site using any MWS  PHP API. What is the exact API to do the system? Does anyone knows how to do this functionality using MWS in PHP. I've attached my sample CSV file that has one product. [Sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/home?select=test.csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the MWS API's SubmitFeed() call, which allows XML uploads as well as "flat file" uploads. You will need to either use the PHP sample code available on the MWS developer site or be ready to fiddle quite a bit with the request details in order to get the signature right.

Be aware though, that just calling SubmitFeed() isn't going to do the trick. Once you call SubmitFeed, you will get an immediate response if the file is accepted or not. If it is accepted, it will be put in a queue, and you'll have to wait for it to be processed by calling GetFeedSubmissionList() repeatedly until it's status has changed.

Only after it has been processed you can call GetFeedSubmissionResult() to see if it had any errors, and if so, which.

The Amazon Seller Support Blog (now defunct) had a nice chart showing the process:

[image]

Depending on the exact nature of the data you want to submit, you may need to go through the above procedure more than once: The XML formats (and to some degree the flat file submissions) expect different feeds for product data, prices, stock information and images.

For more details on the exact nature of these feeds, please refer to the [MWS Feed API Reference](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/index.html). Apart from lots of other more detailed information, it also tells you which types of feeds are available (see "FeedType Enumeration").

Answer (score 0):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
   $dom->loadXML($response->toXML());
   $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
   $dom->formatOutput = true;
   echo $dom->saveXML();
```

use this code to save the result into XML file ....